# Python Requests or Urllib - Use either one to fill out web form?

Tags: python, forms, web, python-requests, urllib

Can either library be used to fill out a web form? I haven't started on any code because i don't know which direction I want to go yet. Basically, I want to have a script go to a website that has a form, fill out some data that's assigned to a variable(s), and submit to get a result. Any direction would be awesome. Thanks y'all!

Comment: Either would work, requests is [recommended](https://docs.python.org/3/library/urllib.request.html#module-urllib.request) these days.

Comment: Any recommendations where to look other than the requests webpage?